# Bitwise operators for normalisation of floating-point numbers and identification of interrupts

Tags: bit-manipulation, interrupt, logical-operators, bit-shift, xor

After having spent a significant amount of time googling this topic, I am still struggling to confidently answer the following two questions:

1. Identify the process using logical operators to normalise a floating-point number.
2. Interrupts from various sources are stored as bits in a binary value.
   How can logical operations be used to identify whether a specific interrupt has been generated?

When it comes to question 1, let's take the number 17 stored in 8-bits for example (00010001).

My initial assumption was, we simply shift it to the left by 2 places. But then what happens to the exponent? Do we use just use XOR to increase/decrease it by the right amount? I'm not sure how to approach this question.

As for the second one, I'm just lost. At first I thought they might be referring to the interrupt masking, but as far as I understand it, that feature is used for temporarily suspending an interrupt, and not for identifying it.

Could someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: It's probably best to ask separate questions in separate posts.

Comment: For the first one, you would really want to *add* 2 to the exponent.  It's not clear from the question whether they are expecting you to essentially write an [adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)) to do the addition using only logical operators, or what; I would ask whoever set the question to clarify.  But details would depend on the exact floating-point format you are using, which hasn't been specified.  In some you may have an implicit leading 1, so 17 = 1.0001 x 2^4 would be encoded with a mantissa of `00010000` and an exponent of 4.

Comment: I think the second one is just asking you how to test if a specific bit is set, i.e. using AND with a mask.

Comment: Re: Question 1, I'm struggling to understand what happens to the binary point when the binary shift is executed. If we take the number 1.75 for example, represented as 000001.11 in 8-bits. If I shift it to the right, I will lose the 1's. If I shift it to the left, how will the computer know where to put the binary point?

Comment: Where the binary point goes is specified as part of the floating-point format, which again you have not stated so we can't know for sure.  But it's common, e.g in [IEEE 754 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), that the mantissa is encoded with an implicit "1." to the left of it, i.e. the binary point always goes at the far left, with a "hidden" 1 bit on the other side of it.  So you shift left 6 bits to make `11000000`, which is understood as `1.11000000`, and you would need an exponent of `0` in this case.

Comment: @NateEldredge Hmm I see, although the format you've mentioned confuses me, as my A Level course expects me to always start the positive numbers with 01 and negative ones with 10.

Comment: Okay.  I don't think I can be of any more help without more information.

Comment: @NateEldredge That's alright. To be honest the main problem lies with how vague my textbook and these questions are. I appreciate your help nonetheless.